# How to handle normalization on mongoDB collections?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

There are two collections `Employee` and 'Project', **It need to maintain history** of project allocations for employee as well as projects basis.

I have created collection schema but it duplicates the data, is there any other way I can achieve this?

> Employee Schema

```
const employeeSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    project: {
        start: {
            type: Date,
            required: true
        },
        end: {
            type: Date,
            required: true
        },
        project: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Project',
            required: true
        }
    },
}
```

> Project Schema

```
const projectSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    employee: {
        start: {
            type: Date,
            required: true
        },
        end: {
            type: Date,
            required: true
        },
        project: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Employee'
        }
    }
});
```

Or Can I create separate collection for mapping both project and employee? if I do this then what is the difference between MongoDB and RDBMS?

Comment: Your structure is confusing... You have a relation of 1:1 of employee and project? It would make more sense for `Project` to don't reference employees, and `Employee` to have and `Array` of projects, with `start` and `end` dates. What are you trying to accomplish with this structure?

Comment: Why do you choose the schemaless DB when you need fixed schema and normalization. I strongly recommend you to take a look into this article https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-1

Comment: @jpenna I am trying to achieve `Two-Way Referencing`

Comment: @Neodan Thanks for link